# Closing an activity using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I want to close an activity at a certain time. Is it possible to close this activity using AlarmManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i havent tried it with finishing an activity, but i am sure that it works.

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.finish();
        Log.i(TAG," get activity-reference --> this ");
        }
    };

    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.cocus.panicbutton.anotherbroadcast") );          
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent("com.cocus.panicbutton.anotherbroadcast"),0 );
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)(context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

    Log.i(TAG,"receiver registered");
// starting the Alarm-Timer    
    am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +2*1000, pi);
// 2*1000 = 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to receive a broadcast as the response from the alarm and send broadcast to a non-static receiver in the activity that if the user is in the activity it will receive it and in the onReceive hit finish

**EDIT:**
What I meant was to use a static BroadcastReceiver to receive the AlarmManager broadcast. that said receiver will send broadcast to a dynamic instance of BroadcastReceiver (that will listen on onStart and stop on onStop). the reason to do this, is because the AlarmManager callback will call even if the Activity is not in the foreground or even exists (User exits the app before the alarm has accured) therefore static BroadcastReceiver. in case the user didn't exit the app, that's when the dynamic-allocated BroadcastReceiver comes in to place.
the onReceive method of the dynamically-allocated receiver is the one that will call `ActivityName.this.finish()` to actually destroy the current activity.
Read more about [BroadcastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) , [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Comment: I though i could use 2 receivers. The first one calls the true activity at a specific time, and a second receiver that calls a new activity (with the CLEAR_TOP flag) to close the other one. I tried it, but the second activity is created, but it doesn't close the other one. Why?